# How do I make a player die when they step off a certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I keep finding things for when people *step on* a block, but I need for when they *step off* a block.

I'm trying to make a command set on 1.16 where if a player were to *no longer* step on 1 of 2 specified blocks *(example: stone and cobblestone)* they will die.

A friend asked me to make this for them since they are trying to do a survival challenge in Minecraft where they are only allowed to be on specific blocks, claiming this will help reinforce the rules. If makin it 2 blocks is not possible then that's alright.

Commands that start off with `/execute @p ~~~ detect ~~~` seem to return errors each time I try to run them. In fact, any commands that have `~~~ detect~~~` always fail no matter what I put.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the commands you've found so far that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this use the following

```
/execute@e[type=player] ~~~ detect ~~~ minecraft:stone 0 kill@e[type=player]
```

the detect will see if a(n) entity steps on a certain block.
IF the entity is on that block then the command will execute. Any other block you want them to die on then set up a chain command block

Comment: This command is broken there are missing so many spaces I dont trust it